# angular-wysiwyg form validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, wysiwyg

I'm trying to use `angular-wysiwyg` and form validation. Instead of using the standard `form.textArea.$dirty` I've been updating a flag on the scope:

```js
$scope.onTextChange = function (value) {
  $scope.textContent = value;
  $scope.isContentDirty = true;
  ...
}
```

Then I can use the property on my button:

```html
<button ng-diabled="isContentDirty"></button>
```

But I'd prefer to do something like this:

```html
<wysiwyg name="myTextArea" ng-model="textContent"></wysiwyg>

<button ng-disabled="!form.myTextArea.$dirty></button>
```

How could I make this work?

Here's an open issue sort of related:
https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg/issues/43

Here are the docs for this directive:    https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg#usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that made me happy enough. It turns out that you can check the validity of any form item by reference, ie:

`myForm.editor.$error`

which would reference errors on the "editor" form item here:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <wysiwyg name="editor"></wysiwyg>
</form>
```

When you go to the link step in the directive, you can set $parsers, which essentially allow you to invalidate your form if some conditions are met:

```
angular.module('foo').directive('wysiwyg', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel', //the 'value' of the form item
        template: 'my template',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            function checkCustomError(viewValue) {
                valid = viewValue.someCondition === 'someValue';
                ngModel.$setValidity('customError', valid);
                return viewValue;
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(checkCustomError);
        }
    }
}
```

And the error would show up under `formName.directiveName.$error.customError`

There are other ways to invalidate the `ngModel` as well, such as putting `ng-maxlength` on the directive, but I thought this was the most informative way of explaining.